# when configuring mod_wsgi for django 1.4 apache fails to start on mac osx after adding WSGIPythonPath to the virtual host config

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I followed the django docs on how to deploy django 1.4 to apache using mod_wsgi https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ on mac osx lion and when I add the WSGIPythonPath directive apache cant restart .Yet without it my app is non existant in the path . In the log I am getting an error that reads

> WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within VirtualHost section

here is what my virtual host config looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin jmured@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "/Users/jamo/code/work/projects/bfpd/fapp"
ServerName bfpd.dev
ServerAlias bfpd.dev
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/bfpd.dev-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/bfpd.dev-access_log" common
Alias /static/ /Users/jamo/code/work/projects/bfpd/fapp/fapp/static/
<Directory /Users/jamo/code/work/projects/bfpd/fapp/fapp/static>
  Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/jamo/code/work/projects/bfpd/fapp/fapp/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /Users/jamo/code/work/projects/bfpd/fapp/  
    <Directory /Users/jamo/code/work/projects/bfpd/fapp/fapp>
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
```

what am i doing wrong ???

Comment: fixed the `WSGIPythonPath /Users/jamo/code/work/projects/bfpd/fapp/` should be in the http.conf

Comment: you should answer your own question then accept it in 2 days so that others can see this answer easily. Glad you got it figured out! I'm sure it will help someone in the future.

Comment: What if deploying on a shared server without write access to httpd, are there any other alternatives?

Comment: @hobs: If you don't have access to the httpd.conf, but you can access vhost files, use mod_wsgi in daemon mode: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed it.
`WSGIPythonPath /Users/jamo/code/work/projects/bfpd/fapp/` 
should be in `http.conf`

Comment: But how can I do when I have several Django applications on the same server (each defined in a different VirtualHost at different URL) ?

Comment: Actually, this error doesn't show up as long as you define `WSGIPythonPath` outside of a `VirtualHost` node. This is true for even *nix stacks.

Comment: @MartinTrigaux, the docs say: `If multiple directories are specified they should be separated by a ':' if using a UNIX like system, or ';' if using Windows. If any part of a directory path contains a space character, the complete argument string to WSGIPythonPath must be quoted.`

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comment by nemesisfixx, and specified by the error in your original question:

> WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within VirtualHost section

Moving WSGIPythonPath outside of VirtualHost resolved Apache crashing on OS X server.

```
$ cat sites/0000_any_80_mysite.com.conf
WSGIPythonPath /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/mysite/django-app:/Users/owen/.virtualenvs/mysite:/Users/owen/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/mysite/site"
    ...
    WSGIScriptAlias /api /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/mysite/django-app/mysite/wsgi.wsgi
    ...
<VirtualHost>
```

It took a lot of putzing for me to get the paths correct (including full path to site-env, which I initially thought would be included automatically after adding the virtualenv top level).