# Apache Conf file issue -WSGIPythonPath error

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

So i'm trying to deploy a simple website using django, Apache, and wsgi. I wrote my conf file using the django guide (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and this previous answer ([Deploying Django on Apache and WSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331641/deploying-django-on-apache-and-wsgi?newreg=f4e7765683624f9691def37724ada805)) but when I restart Apache I get an syntax error  on line 3 stating WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within the VirtualHost section, once removed Apache restarted successfully but still does not redirect to the appropriate django website I created even after changing the hosts files so that it redirects back to my server.

Apache Version: 2.4.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Django Version: 1.8.3

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mywebsite/mywebsite/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath /var/www/mywebsite   

    ServerAdmin my_email@gmail.com
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com

    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite/mywebsite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you add more description in your title it's likely this question will get more attention.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955880/when-configuring-mod-wsgi-for-django-1-4-apache-fails-to-start-on-mac-osx-after). It has solution for exactly your problem.

Comment: so i basically move the WSGIPythonPath to the apache2.conf file? Edit: ok i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

move the line with WSGIPythonPath to the httpd.conf location

Comment: Better still use mod_wsgi daemon mode. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html Using a daemon process you can then set the Python path and virtual environment location just for that daemon process.